# How do I merge 2 JFrames?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

im having trouble finding out a way to merge the two JFrames in the code. I basically need the grid and stuff from one of the JFrames and an extra border around it. Because I need some buttons added to it. Here's the full code:

```
 package opimejpanelit;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OpimeJpanelit {

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame = new JFrame("Huinjaa");
        frame.setSize(1000, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        new OpimeJpanelit();
        //adds JPanel
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setSize(900,600);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
        public OpimeJpanelit() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int columnCount = 9;
        private int rowCount = 7;
        private java.util.List<Rectangle> cells;
        private Point selectedCell;

        public TestPane() {
            cells = new ArrayList<>(columnCount * rowCount);
            MouseAdapter mouseHandler;
            mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point point = e.getPoint();

                    int width = getWidth();
                    int height = getHeight();

                    int cellWidth = width / columnCount;
                    int cellHeight = height / rowCount;

                    int column = e.getX() / cellWidth;
                    int row = e.getY() / cellHeight;

                    selectedCell = new Point(column, row);
                    repaint();

                }
            };
            addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            cells.clear();
            selectedCell = null;
            super.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            int cellWidth = width / columnCount;
            int cellHeight = height / rowCount;

            int xOffset = (width - (columnCount * cellWidth)) / 2;
            int yOffset = (height - (rowCount * cellHeight)) / 2;

            if (cells.isEmpty()) {
                for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
                        Rectangle cell = new Rectangle(
                                xOffset + (col * cellWidth),
                                yOffset + (row * cellHeight),
                                cellWidth,
                                cellHeight);
                        cells.add(cell);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (selectedCell != null) {

                int index = selectedCell.x + (selectedCell.y * columnCount);
                Rectangle cell = cells.get(index);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.fill(cell);

            }




            g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            for (Rectangle cell : cells) {
                g2d.draw(cell);
            }



            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? How do you imagine it to behave?

Comment: e.g. Oracle tutorial about CardLayout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is very hard to interpret - can you describe more of what you would like to see, perhaps with a picture?  You talk about "merging" `JFrame`s, but it's not clear from your code where you are even trying to do that.  You have a `frame` vriable that is a member of the top level class and set from `main()` and also another with the same name (usually confusing / bad practice) local to the constructor of that class.  Are you trying to act on the same `JFrame` in both these places?  We need more description of what you want to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, It is not possible to merge two `JFrame`.

With a look at your code, It looks like you have tried adding up `JPanel` in the same container, but instead u created a new `JFrame` for it.

You can try using `remove(component)` method in `JFrame` to remove and add components again(If helpful).

If possible, Please provide a better clarity or pictorial representation of what you are trying to achieve.